# different fragment and different item on grid layout use recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello I had a problem about in the fragment view, each fragment has the same RecyclerView picture even though the shape has changed and different results remain the same in each fragment like this: [image: Screenshots]

So the image is still the same as in import fragments and transactions cannot be deleted but if given a background like a picture 3 it can be lost but cannot be used which can be used only the previous image to be like stacked.

This is my main activity that made it all wrong:

**MainActivity.xml**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private List<Tas> lstTas;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstTas = new ArrayList<>();
        lstTas.add(new Tas("Tas Serbaguna Sedang", "Kategori : Tas Lokal", "Deskripsi Tas : Tas serbaguna yang bisa menyimpan berbagai alat make up maupun perlengkapan lainnya", "Rp 70.000", R.drawable.greybag));
        lstTas.add(new Tas("Tas Serbaguna Mini", "Kategori : Tas Lokal", "Deskripsi Tas : Tas serbaguna yang bisa menyimpan berbagai alat make up maupun perlengkapan lainnya dengan ukuran mini", "Rp 50.000", R.drawable.bagmini));
        lstTas.add(new Tas("Tas Serbaguna Besar", "Kategori : Tas Lokal", "Deskripsi Tas : Tas serbaguna yang bisa menyimpan berbagai alat make up maupun perlengkapan lainnya dengan ukuran besar", "Rp 150.000", R.drawable.bagblack));
        lstTas.add(new Tas("Pouch Wanita Sedang", "Kategori : Pouch", "Deskripsi Tas : Dompet Pouch Trendy yang muat banyak barang dan trendy di bawa kemana saja", "Rp 20.000", R.drawable.pouch));
        lstTas.add(new Tas("Tas Pink Mini", "Kategori : Tas Import", "Deskripsi Tas : Tas Import mini bag yang bisa menyimpan peralatan mandi ataupun kebutuhan sehari - hari wanita", "Rp.120.000", R.drawable.pinkmini));
        lstTas.add(new Tas("Tote Bag Campus", "Kategori : Tas Import", "Deskripsi Tas : Tote Bag cocok untuk kalian yang masih kuliah untuk menyimpan perlengkapan kuliah", "Rp.90.000", R.drawable.totebag));
        lstTas.add(new Tas("Fold Tote Bag", "Kategori : Tas Import", "Deskripsi Tas : Tote Bag lipat yang bisa di lipat cocok untuk para remaja yang suka simple membawa barang saat berpergian", "Rp.100.000", R.drawable.totebagorange));

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        TextView name = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nama);
        TextView email = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.mail);
        String extraName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String extraEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        name.setText(extraName);
        email.setText(extraEmail);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BerandaFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_beranda);
        }

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_beranda:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BerandaFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_taslokal:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TasLokalFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_tasimport:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TasImportFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_status:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new StatusFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_belanja:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new KeranjangFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_komplain:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new KomplainFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_refund:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new RefundFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_pengaturan:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PengaturanFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                }
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });


        RecyclerView mrv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewtas);
        RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstTas);
        mrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        mrv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mrv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```java
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Tas> mData;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Tas> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_tas, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tv_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tas_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getImg());
        holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TasActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Title", mData.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Category", mData.get(position).getCategory());
                intent.putExtra("Description", mData.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("Harga", mData.get(position).getHarga());
                intent.putExtra("Img", mData.get(position).getImg());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_title;
        ImageView tas_thumbnail;
        CardView card;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texttas);
            tas_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagetas);
            card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardviewid);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is I still use this code or I changed the adapter or some else code to make it easy? Cause I had mixed code from another page on stack overflows it won't happen.

Comment: the error always like this which the adapter is on there RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: "It's solved thanks" ?? please add the answer here then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just changed the list and made a different adapter for it but on fragment in import and the first picture i just used same list but different collection of list like this

```
lstTas = new ArrayList<>();
    lstTas.add(new Tas("Tas Serbaguna Sedang", "Kategori : Tas Lokal", "Deskripsi Tas : Tas serbaguna yang bisa menyimpan berbagai alat make up maupun perlengkapan lainnya", "Rp 70.000", R.drawable.greybag));
    lstTas.add(new Tas("Pouch Wanita Sedang", "Kategori : Pouch", "Deskripsi Tas : Dompet Pouch Trendy yang muat banyak barang dan trendy di bawa kemana saja", "Rp 20.000", R.drawable.pouch));
    lstTas.add(new Tas("Tas Pink Mini", "Kategori : Tas Import", "Deskripsi Tas : Tas Import mini bag yang bisa menyimpan peralatan mandi ataupun kebutuhan sehari - hari wanita", "Rp.120.000", R.drawable.pinkmini));
    lstTas.add(new Tas("Tote Bag Campus", "Kategori : Tas Import", "Deskripsi Tas : Tote Bag cocok untuk kalian yang masih kuliah untuk menyimpan perlengkapan kuliah", "Rp.90.000", R.drawable.totebag));
    lstTas.add(new Tas("Fold Tote Bag", "Kategori : Tas Import", "Deskripsi Tas : Tote Bag lipat yang bisa di lipat cocok untuk para remaja yang suka simple membawa barang saat berpergian", "Rp.100.000", R.drawable.totebagorange));
```

just on different collection on Array list in each page